# connect to bucket having uppercase letter

Tags: boto

I am not able to connect to a bucket if the bucket name has a Upper case letter.
I have several buckets those has capital letter in it.

```
>>> mybucket = conn.get_bucket('Vig_import')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 391, in get_bucket
    bucket.get_all_keys(headers, maxkeys=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 360, in get_all_keys
    '', headers, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 317, in _get_all
    query_args=s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 462, in make_request
    host = self.calling_format.build_host(self.server_name(), bucket)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 86, in build_host
    return self.get_bucket_server(server, bucket)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 65, in wrapper
    if len(args) == 3 and check_lowercase_bucketname(args[2]):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 57, in check_lowercase_bucketname
    raise BotoClientError("Bucket names cannot contain upper-case " \
boto.exception.BotoClientError: BotoClientError: Bucket names cannot contain upper-case characters when using either the sub-domain or virtual hosting calling format.
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

S3 recommend that you only use DNS-compliant bucket names.

Take a look at the restrictions page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

However you do it, in boto you can use a different calling format for buckets with a mixed-case name:

```
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat

conn = boto.connect_s3(calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())
mybucket = conn.get_bucket('Vig_import')
```

Answer (score 1):

To addings those lines to **.boto** file are worked for me

```
[s3]
calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat
```

[Referance](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836#issuecomment-67896932)

Comment: how can I locate the .boto file? I did Cmd + Shift + . and can see files in my Finder but can't locate that one. Also looked through my site-packages/boto but didn't see it there. Would appreciate any info on this!