# How can I bypass the boto3 function not allowing uppercase letters in bucket name?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I need to get a list of s3 keys from a bucket. I have a script that works great with boto3. The issue is that the bucket name I'm using has uppercase letters and this throws an error with boto3.

In looking at [connect to bucket having uppercase letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088584/connect-to-bucket-having-uppercase-letter) this uses boto, but I'd like to use boto3 but `OrdinaryCallingFormat()` doesn't seem to be an option for boto3.

Or, I could adapt the script to work for boto, but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried:

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key, 
calling_format = OrdinaryCallingFormat())

Bucketname = s3.get_bucket('b-datasci/x-DI-S')
```

but that gave the error `boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 404 Not Found.`

With this attempt:

```
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(
    'us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,               
    calling_format=boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(Bucketname)
```

I got the error: `xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:0: no element found`

How can I get this to work with boto, or else integrate `OrdinaryCallingFormat()`into boto3 to list the keys?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a bucket called `b-datasci/x-DI-S`? I don't think bucket names can contain a slash. In the old days, buckets in US-East-1 were allowed uppercase letters, but now all regions require DNS-compliant names that work in URLs. As such, they need to be lowercase and contain a limited set of characters.

Comment: Because bucket name is going to be used as part of the signed-url hostname, .e.g.  `http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/yourobject`, any non-DNS compliant simply create support problem for AWS.  E.g. converting unicode bucket automatically to punycode will not help, it just create confusion.

Comment: Yes the problem was the bucket name. In fact the 2nd piece of code above does work, when I added this: for key in bucket.get_all_keys(prefix='s-DI-S/', delimiter='/') and took what was really the prefix off the Bucketname.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the an uppercase character.  It's the slash.

Bucket name must match this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$
```

To list objects in bucket "mybucket" with prefix "b-datasci/x-DI-S", you're going too low-level.  Use this instead:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
for obj in client.list_objects_v2(Bucket="mybucket", Prefix="b-datasci/x-DI-S"):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @John Rotenstein , all bucket name must be DNS-compliant, so a direct slash is not allowed for bucket name.

> In fact the 2nd piece of code above does work, when I added this: for
>   key in bucket.get_all_keys(prefix='s-DI-S/', delimiter='/') and took
>   what was really the prefix off the Bucketname.

From the above OP comment,  it seems OP maybe misunderstood S3 object store with a file directory system.  Each s3 object are never store in a hierarchy format. The so call "prefix"  is simply an text filter that retrieve object name that contains the the similar "prefix" in the object name.

In OP, there is a bucket name call  `b-datasci`, while there are many object with the prefix `x-DI-S` store under the bucket.

In addition, the usage of `delimiter` under `get_all_keys` is not what OP think. If you check out AWS documentation on [Listing Keys Hierarchically Using a Prefix and Delimiter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html), you will learn that it is just a secondary filter.  i.e.

> The prefix and delimiter parameters limit the kind of results returned by a list operation. Prefix limits results to only those keys that begin with the specified prefix, and delimiter causes list to roll up all keys that share a common prefix into a single summary list result.

p/s: OP should use boto3 because boto is deprecated by AWS for more than 2 years.